# Iteração entre Lista e Dicionário, lidar com exceções

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando lidar com valores que não existem em uma iteração entre os itens de uma lista e as chaves de um dicionário.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dicionario = {"1": {"x": 77.25, "y": 116.330078125},
              "2": {"x": 88.25, "y": 126.330078125},
              "3": {"x": 99.25, "y": 136.330078125}}
novo_dicionario = {}

for item in lista:
    for key, value in dicionario.items():
        if str(item) == key:
            for v in value.items():
                if v[0] in list(novo_dicionario.keys()):
                    novo_dicionario[v[0]].append(v[1])
                else:
                    novo_dicionario[v[0]] = [v[1]]
```

Resultando:

```
{'x': [77.25, 88.25, 99.25], 'y': [116.330078125, 126.330078125, 136.330078125]}
```

Como podem ver, "1, 2, 3" existem como chave no dicionário. Porém "4 e 5" não. Então nesse caso, eu gostaria que meu resultado lidasse com essa exceção e ficasse dessa maneira:

```
{'x': [77.25, 88.25, 99.25, 0.00], 'y': [116.330078125, 126.330078125, 136.330078125, 0.00]}
```

E conforme a lista fosse aumentando e não fosse encontrado como chave no dicionário, "0.00" fossem adicionados na quantidade respectiva.

Comment: `if item in dicionario: ...` seria isso?

Comment: @bfavaretto com esse codigo ele imprime a quantidade de vezes que tem o tem no dicionario

Answer (score 0):

> Texto do autor da pergunta antes publicado na própria pergunta.

Resolvido no fórum em ingles.

```
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key in lista:
    if str(key) in dicionario:
        adict = dicionario[str(key)]
        result['x'].append(adict['x'])
        result['y'].append(adict['y'])
    else:
        result['x'].append(0.00)
        result['y'].append(0.00)

print(dict(result))
```

Comment: Caso o autor da pergunta queira  publicar a sua própria resposta removo essa publicação.